# How to get array items with customs relationship?

Tags: javascript

I have an array which contains three items, these items are linked each other by a reference property called `bound_id`, this is the array:

```
[
   { id: "1", option: { bound_id: "2" }},
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "12" }},
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
]
```

as you can see the item with id `1` is linked with the item with id `2`, and the item `2` is linked to the item `12`.

Now, suppose I change the value of `bound_id` of item `1` to `null`:

```
[
   { id: "1", option: { bound_id: null }},
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "12" }},
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
]
```

how can I return all the items which are not linked each other? The expected result should be:

```
[
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "12" }}
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
]
```

this means that the next item in the array doesn't have the relationship with the current id, so if the relationship is broken the result need to return all the items that doesn't fit any more in this relationship.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove all the items which have `bound_id` set to `null`

```js
const input = [
   { id: "1", option: { bound_id: null }},
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "12" }},
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
];

const output = input.filter(a => a.option.bound_id);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: this seems to work, is possible also specify to prevent to insert the first item? the first item must be even available..

Comment: @teres sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you please clarify a bit further? This answer just filters out all the objects which have a value for `bound_id`.

Comment: I mean: if in `input` is available only one value, the `output` will also include the only item available, this is not correct. I guess a better implementation is add all the items with no relationship but following the item with broken relation, eg: if the relationship was broken by id 2 the id 1 shouldn't be included in the `output` but only the id 12, make sense?